# Select default value in a drop-down menu at run-time

Tags: java, html, drop-down-menu

Suppose we've a drop down menu like this

```
<select name="op" >  
    <option value="1">A</option>  
    <option value="2">B</option>  
    <option value="3">C</option>  
</select>
```

Now, I need to specify that option with value "2" should be the default (I only know this when the page is being called so can't hardcode the default value)
Am I correct that I need to get above code segment turned (at runtime) into something like

```
<select name="op" >  
    <option value="1">A</option>  
    <option selected value="2">B</option>  
    <option value="3">C</option>  
</select>
```

or is there a better/ easier way for which one won't need to iterate through each of the option value comparing and if a match is found adding the "selected" part in that line?

Comment: What is the technology here? Is there a backing bean you use? How do you generate the HTML?

Comment: Till now it was simply written like static html code segment from "<select>" to "/select> (the page is in jsp)

Comment: I guess iterating through your data and adding `selected` is easiest to implement then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's it. But usually

1. Your list of values will be dynamic as well, and you'll have to iterate through it to generate your HTML options anyway
2. You'll use some web framework which will provide JSP tags and/or UI components handling this for you. Your code will then look like this:

   `<s:select name="op">
       <s:options optionsCollection="${actionBean.theOptions}" value="id" label="name"/>
   </s:select>`

Answer (score 1):

you can set default value at runtime using javascript and JQuery like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquerylatest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('select[name=op] option[value=2]')attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="op">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

but one thing makes me wonder. if it is "written like static html code segment" as you stated why setting the default value at runtime?

Comment: Ahh, actually till now static was fine, but now I needed to just chose the default option based on something entered by user on the previous page. The options are still predefined and could be hard coded. Guess this approach of using static code segment isn't a good practice? just wanted to keep things simple and save any overhead of creating the whole list at runtime.